# How can I build more than 12 buildings in Europa Universalis without using a mod?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I have Europa Universalis with patch 1.19. I am also using the extended timeline mod. This mod adds a lot of buildings to the game. Unfortunately, it seems impossible to build more than 12 buildings in a province. I know that there is a mod which gives 16 building slots. I do not use steam, so, I cannot download the mod. Is there a way to edit the game files and give me more building slots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is, as of version 1.19, not possible I fear.

You can use [this](http://steamworkshopdownloader.com/) site to straight download Steam Mods for installing it manually.

The mod might easily be compatible with 1.19 since unless the building slots system was changed since that patch (which I doubt) the only difference is the verison specified in the .mod folder.

I would also like to add that we discourage piracy.